# Generic navigation listener for whole application

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to find a way to setup a **global** Navigation listener in the **Root** of my app (MaterialApp) which can allow me to track all **navigation events** including the actual *route name* (*/home/page1* for ex.), navigation *type* etc.

I search something like:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/',
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) => route(settings),
  onNavigationChange: (RouteType type, String currentRoute) {
    // type can an enum be like: 'pop', 'push', 'replace' etc.
    // currentRoute is the current route name defined in a pushNamed for example
  }
),
```

Note: this code is **non functional**, only to illustrate what I want ;)

During my search, I found quite some solutions like [RouteObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html), [route_observer_mixin](https://pub.dev/packages/route_observer_mixin) which are almost what I'm looking for but I need to wrap all my pages with a mixin... so no a global solution :/

Do you have any clues ?

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT thanks to @pskink**, see the solution below

Comment: you have `MaterialApp.navigatorObservers` property

Comment: @pskink Thanks for your answer but ```navigatorObservers``` need to setup a mixin on all my children pages, I only want to setup once :/

Comment: what mixin? you don't need any mixin, simply add one concrete `NavigatorObserver` in the list of observers

Comment: OH ! My bad yes !! This is working perfeclty now ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @pskink I had edited my issue to help others, thanks again for your help :)

Comment: sure, you're welcone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution is to create an extends of the RouteObserver like this:

```dart
class MyNavigatorObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {
  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
    if (route is PageRoute) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic> newRoute, Route<dynamic> oldRoute}) {
    super.didReplace(newRoute: newRoute, oldRoute: oldRoute);
    if (newRoute is PageRoute) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
    if (previousRoute is PageRoute && route is PageRoute) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

and then setup it on the MaterialApp widget:

```dart
static MyNavigatorObserver observer =
  new MyNavigatorObserver();

MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/',
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) => route(settings),
  navigatorObservers: [observer],
),
```

Thanks @pskink !

Comment: actually extend `NavigatorObserver`, not `RouteObserver` - it's more or less the same but ...

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @pskink, I've build a generic observer for logging purposes.

Designed to work with navigation 1.0 and **unamed** routes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GlobalNavigatorObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute> {
  @override
  void didPush(route, previousRoute) {
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
    _log('push', previousRoute, route);
  }

  @override
  void didPop(route, previousRoute) {
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
    _log('pop', route, previousRoute);
  }

  void _log(String method, Route? fromRoute, Route? toRoute) {
    debugPrint('[Navigator] ${_getPageName(fromRoute)} => ${_getPageName(toRoute)} ($method)');
  }

  /// Try to get page name from route.
  String _getPageName(dynamic route) {
    // Because the builder field is not on a common class, we must try dynamically.
    try {
      final routeBuilderString = route.builder.toString();   // Example: 'Closure: (BuildContext) => WashingsPage'
      return routeBuilderString.substring(routeBuilderString.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
    } catch(_) {
      return 'X';
    }
  }
}
```